# Why does a number less than 0.1 and greater than 1e-7 get converted in scientific notation?

Tags: javascript, scientific-notation

```
(0.1).toString() //0.1
(0.000001).toString() //0.000001
(0.000009).toString() //0.000009
```

Why do the above numbers get converted normally, but

```
(0.0000001).toString() //1e-7
(0.0000008).toString() //8e-7
(0.0000000000089).toString() // 8.9e-12
```

these are displayed in scientific notation?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the spec(*ecma-262*) specified it.

**9.8.1** [ToString Applied to the Number Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8.1)